# C operator -- gives two different results

Tags: c, operators

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,d,b,c;
    a = 10;
    c = 10;
    d = --c + --c+1; 
    b = --a +1+ --a ;
    printf("b= %d, d = %d" , b,d);
    return 0;
}
```

b= 18, d = 17

[the code and it's run](http://ideone.com/8n2bb3)

Why d&b are not equal? can you please explain why d=17?

Comment: [Undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Interesting. In codepad b and d are both equal to 17. http://codepad.org/xfCWITcq

Comment: By the way ... you should use `include` instead of `import`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh right, it's because it's undefined when the value of `a` and `c` will decrement.

```
d = --c + --c+1;
```

If `c` is decremented twice and then `d` is calculated, then it gives

```
d = 8 + 8 + 1 = 17
```

But if `c` is decremented as we proceed from left to right, then it gives

```
d = 9 + 8 + 1 = 18
```

Comment: Following the equation the way the OP wrote it, `d = --c` (which is 9) `+ --c` (which is 8) `+ 1`; that's why I went in that order.